# Show that $T(x+1)=xT(x)$ if $T(x)=\int _0 ^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1} dt$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I need to calculate the following: the integral is from 0 to infinity

I am given that $ T(x) = \int \limits _0 ^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1} dt$.

I need to show that $ T(x+1)=xT(x) $.

So my logic was to plug $x+1$ for $x$ which gives

$ T(x)=\int \limits _0 ^\infty e^{-t} t^x dt $

However I am not quite sure how to integrate this, I have an idea that it should be integration by parts but I am not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried integrating by parts?

Comment: Try integration by parts. This is the logic behind the Gamma function as well.

Comment: Differentiate $t^x$ and integrate $e^{-t}$.

Comment: Yes that was what I was planning to do but if you differentiate t^x does that give you xt^(x-1)  not sure how I would make the integral of $ uv-\int vdu $ simplify down

Comment: The term $uv$ should vanish.

Comment: Which still leaves me with a integral that does not simplify

Comment: You want to show $T(x+1)=xT(x)$, so you should expect to have an integral on both sides of the equation. The integral you get on the right should be in exactly the form you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need $x > 0$ for the improper integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{x-1}\; dt$ to converge.  This is the definition of the Gamma function.

Yes, you can use integration by parts.  In the integral for $T(x+1)$, try $u = t^x$ and $dv = e^{-t}\; dt$.

Comment: Yes that was what I was planning to do but if you differentiate t^x does that give you xt^(x-1) not sure how I would make the integral of uv−∫vdu simplify down

Comment: @javahelper123: The term $uv \Big| _0 ^\infty $ is $0$, because $\Bbb e ^{-t}$ is $0$ in $\infty$ and $t^x$ is $0$ in $0$.

Comment: @AlexM. "$e^{-t}$ is $0$ in $\infty$" is not enough.   More precisely, $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-t} t^x = 0$ because $e^{-t}$ decays faster than any power of $t$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yes, this is what I had in mind.